# How to iterate through the bars from current bar to the beginning of the day?

Tags: pine-script

I am tryin to iterate from the current bar (in real time) back to the first bar of the day, 6:30 for me. This is the code that I have and it isn't working.

```
loop_here = time_tradingday //set variable to loop back to beginning of day  
    if barstate.islast
        for i to loop_here // looping back to beginning of day
            (expressions here)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ta.change(time("D"))` function will return `true` on the first bar of each day.

`ta.barssince()` function will return the number of bars since a condition is met.

Combine those two functions, and you'll get the number of bars from current bar to the bar in the beginning of the day. From there you can just use a for loop:

```
new_day = ta.change(time("D"))
bars_since_new_day = ta.barssince(new_day)

for i=0 to bars_since_new_day
    // do something
```